# My Protractor test is hanging when trying to determine if an element is present

Tags: protractor, ui-automation

I have a protractor test set up that does the most basic thing imaginable. It logs into a web app. Everything seems to be going fine until I try to evaluate if the login was successful or not by looking for the existence of an element on the subsequent page. I'm sure this is a synchronization issue, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Things to note:

- I'm fairly new to javascript (though not to coding), so code improvement suggestions would be appreciated.
- The login function works like a charm, including the wait.
- Async / Promises / Awaits are still breaking my brain a little bit.

**Login Method**

```
this.login = async function (repo, username, password, domain) {
    if (repo == null){ repo = REPO_UNDER_TEST; }

    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    await this.openLoginPage(domain).
        then( this.selectRepo(repo) ).
        then( this.usernameTextBox.sendKeys(username) ).
        then( this.passwordTextBox.sendKeys(password) ).
        then( this.signInButton.click() ).
        then( async function() {
            console.log(`I'm starting my WAIT at ${Date().toString()}`);
            await browser.wait(
                EC.titleIs(repo), 
                32000
            );
        } )
};
```

**Test Code**

```
describe('Login Tests', function () {
it('should log you in given a good username/password', async function () {
    console.log(`I'm starting my TEST at ${Date().toString()}`);
    await loginPage.login(null, 'edwin', 'e', null);
    console.log(`I'm starting my EVAL at ${Date().toString()}`);

    var searchBox = element.all(by.model('searchQuery'));        
    expect(searchBox.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();

    });  
});
```

The console.logs are just there to make sure things are happening in the correct order. If I comment out the line where I'm expecting the searchBox to be present the test runs to completion and evaluates the simple expect(true).toBeTruthy() correctly. If I attempt to run the expect for the searchBox the test just hangs until I shut it down manually. The console will then tell me that the expect failed because the item doesn't exist even though it is clearly visible on the screen prior to the console.log stating that the eval is starting.

**Log Output**

```
[10:22:42] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

Started

I'm starting my TEST at Wed Feb 27 2019 10:22:45 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

I'm starting my WAIT at Wed Feb 27 2019 10:22:46 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

I'm starting my EVAL at Wed Feb 27 2019 10:23:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

F

Failures:

1) Login Tests should log you in given a good username/password

  Message:
    Expected false to be true.

  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at UserContext.<anonymous> 

(C:\GIT\TestFramework_POCs\protract\TESTS\login-spec.js:15:39)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)


1 spec, 1 failure

Finished in 37.295 seconds


[10:23:22] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

[10:23:22] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)

[10:23:22] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)

[10:23:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, this is most likely a result of async issues. Even though your login function works fine, I would personally write it using all `await` instead of  `.then()` such as

```
this.login = async function (repo, username, password, domain) {
if (repo == null){ repo = REPO_UNDER_TEST; }

  await browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

  await this.openLoginPage(domain);
  await this.selectRepo(repo);
  await this.usernameTextBox.sendKeys(username);
  await this.passwordTextBox.sendKeys(password);
  await this.signInButton.click();
  console.log(`I'm starting my WAIT at ${Date().toString()}`);
  await browser.wait(EC.titleIs(repo), 32000);
};
```

While .then() does work, I find it much better/easier to use `await` everywhere. `await` waits the for following action to complete before moving on the the next line of code, which is the same as multiple `.then()` but you avoid the annoying christmas tree functions multiple `.then()` can become.

I don't see anything wrong with your test itself, although checking `isPresent()` on the `element.all` can potentially cause issues, and is where I would guess the problem is. `element` and `element.all` will handle no element being there. For example:

```
element.all(by.css('NothingHere'); // will return array with length of 0
element(by.css('NothingHere'); //will return an ElementFinder object
```

Basically, 0 is a valid response while empty ElementFinder will give an error so if your first check is on `element.all()` it anything is not yet loaded it will happily return 0. However, `element()` will see that there is nothing yet and wait for the element to become visible until it times out If you could find a unique element inside `element.all(by.model('searchQuery'));` and target that instead, I expect it would pass.

Also when using async/await you need to have `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;` inside your conf file

Comment: I appreciate your input here. I tried all of your suggestions, but nothing seemed to work. It seems that the test can find absolutely nothing after the login completes in the test. I am using VSCode to debug and trying to interact/find any element after hitting a breakpoint following the login. I can't interact at all with any of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in your following code:

1) `element.all()` has no `isPresent()`

2) you missed `await` in following code

```
var searchBox = element.all(by.model('searchQuery'));        
expect(await searchBox.get(0).isPresent()).toBe(true);

// or 
var searchBox = element(by.model('searchQuery'));        
expect(await searchBox.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Please confirm how to locator the searchBox

Comment: Good catch.
Unfortunately, it didn't fix to the problem. It seems that I can't interact with the page at all (can't find any elements) following the completion of the login.